# Lookup Function in rdlc vs2010

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008-r2

We have created rdl file with lookup function in sql server 2008 r2.
This Report is working fine. But when we are import in vs2010 website and rename to rdlc that time lookup function is not working.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I found the following:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8774efd3-0e10-44e7-a0a8-4290d28bac65/lookup-in-rdlc-local-report?forum=sqlreportingservices

> The Lookup functionality isn't available in local mode, but it does work if you point the ReportViewer control to your SS2008R2 server.

Which is the reason it works on the server but not in VS 2010.